# How to log to database using the built-in Asp.Net core logging (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog, microsoft-extensions-logging

I have the following code to set up logging to database using NLog. I use an Alpha version of NLog.Extension.Logging. Is it possible to let the built-in log framework log to database so I don't need to use NLog?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want have a reference to NLog at all? Or that you don't want to have to write logging code inside of each controller to log errors?

Comment: I don't want to have a reference to NLog since there is no stable library for it.

Comment: Ahh, okay. There's no built-in library for database logging to my knowledge. You could [create your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36922701/4270650) fairly easily, though.

Comment: If you are not stuck to NLog you could go with Serilog. Microsoft wrote an extension that plus it directly into aspnet core and they have a sink for writing to a database.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: @Leandro I used serilog

Answer (score 1):

There is a NuGet package for that (DISCLAIMER: I made it):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DLogger.Extensions.Logging

The GitHub repository:
https://github.com/SasaCetkovic/DLogger.Extensions.Logging

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on Github that is flexible and available for **EF Core**:

[ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Logging.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/msmolka/ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Logging.EntityFrameworkCore)

It was prepared to use in ASP NET Core application, but it does not contain any references that prevents to use it in plain **.NET Core** application.
Also there is also possibilty to **extend** base Log class.